# Three js 3D rotation

Tags: javascript, matrix, rotation, three.js

I have 2 mesh objects. Anchor and Rod. The Anchor rotates around z-axis, as illustrated by the image. The rod is supposed to move only backward and forwards. 
Here is the image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/7a83.png/.

But i am stuck with trying to figure out the matrix calculation. For example if the anchor rotates 45degrees, so its facing the x-axis, how can i make the rod still move backwards and forwards?

Comment: Do you use gl-matrix.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the rotation around z axis :

```
var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2);
```

For the translation, where z is your delta :

```
var translation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0, z);
```

You can combine the two transformations in beginning with the translation :

<del>var transformation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0, z).makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2);</del>

```
var transformation = rotation.multiply(translation);
```

Then apply transformation to your geometry :

```
geometry.applyMatrix(transformation);
```

Comment: I'm quite new to Three.js so i don't really know what i'm missing here. I got the rotation around z-axis to work, but still can't figure out how to make the "rod" move backwards and forwards when the direction changes. I can't do it with makerotationX because it does not allways rotate around x-axis, if you know what i mean.

Comment: Your transformation is a rotation around z with a rotation around X, so combine the two by multiplying the matrixes : var rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(angleZ); var rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(angleX); var transformation = rotationZ.multiply(rotationX);

Comment: That works, but the problem is that the object needs to move, and applying a matrix rotates it around the worlds origon. so when it moves the rotation gets larger, and larger. I am not sure how to bind the rotation to a single blocks own origon.

Comment: This Answer should NOT be accepted or at least corrected you can't combine transformations by: var transformation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0, z).makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2) - it overwrites them!!! Use something like: var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(this.toolMeshes[index].rotation.z);
                var translation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(this.toolMeshes[index].position.x, this.toolMeshes[index].position.y, 0);
                var matrix = rotation.multiplyMatrices(translation, rotation);

Answer (score 4):

Just as [scooby37](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224708/scooby37) noticed, combination example provided by Troopers is not valid. You should **NOT**:

```
new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0, z).makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2);
```

**Instead** you can try something like:

```
let rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), Math.PI / 6.0);
let transformation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, this.height, 0);
this.mesh.applyMatrix(rotation.multiply(transformation));
```

which introduce matrix multiplication - usual way transformations should be combined.